# Backpacking 46 days in the US with ESTA

Tags: usa, us-visa-waiver-program, backpacking, esta

I am a Greek citizen; this means that I have the chance to travel with ESTA. I have already bought my plane ticket and I will be in San Fransisco for 46 days, taking my backpack and travelling by bus.

Will it be a problem travelling so long as a visitor? They won't regard me harshly for being 46 days as a tourist, will they?

Comment: You would typically get 90 days, if you really plan to be a tourist, there is no reason 46 days should raise red flags. See the official [description of the program on state.gov](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) You can read other questions about ESTA and the “Visa Waiver Program”/VWP on this site for more info on all this.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all.  If you're getting the [ESTA/VWP](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html), it's valid for 90 days travel (there are some weird laws about exiting and coming back in, all has to be done within 90 days if you're doing Canada/Mexico as well), but 46 days is half that!

To have a smooth transition, you'll want to have proof of onward travel, address of your first few nights' accommodation if possible, and ideally a rough itinerary, and proof of funds, although those aren't always asked for. They'll likely question you to ensure your plan isn't unreasonable and that you've thought it through, but then you should be in and able to enjoy the country.

Comment: Thank you very much! I already took the return ticket though and I made reservation to a youth hostel which I am going to stay